# Outlook, multiple add-ins squabbling over the "Send" button

Tags: registry, vsto, send, outlook-addin, harmon.ie

I have two Outlook addins; a 3rd-party one (actually harmon.ie) and one that was built in my firm. Both respond to the "Send" button in Outlook. At the moment, when a user clicks "Send", harmon.ie executes first, followed by our add-in. I need to reverse this sequence but have failed so far. Can anyone offer advice?

Our add-in is built with Visual Studio and uses VSTO. I don't know how harmon.ie is built or how it is triggered by Outlook.

Things I have tried;
Moving keys around in the registry, between HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE and HKEY_CURRENT_USER, in case the sequence is dependent on the order of the keys. With everything under HKEY_CURRENT_USER, both add-ins execute but still in the wrong order, even though our registry entry comes before the harmon.ie one when sorted alphabetically

If I move all the keys to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, our add-in does not execute.

Ideally I need a solution that works for Outlook 2007 plus later versions, but anything that works would be great at this stage!

Thank you for any tips,  best wishes,  Ian

Comment: I have just heard from harmon.ie and our own developers. Both add-ins seem to be using the same event; ApplicationEvents_11_ItemSendEventHandler So I need to find a way to control which add-in gets priority.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to specify the order in which COM addins are loaded or the order of the COM events. Why is it important that your code is executed first?